# Problem completing Ubuntu Server 20.04.3 LTS installation

Tags: boot, server, 20.04

I'm trying to build a small Network around a Ubuntu Server 20.04.3 LTS and I'm having trouble installing the OS.
I get to the screen where I can configure my login name and password and so on but after about 20 seconds on that screen an error message appears:

> Sorry, there was a problem completing the installation.

> [View full report]

> If you want to help improve the installer, you can send an error report

> [Send to canonical]

> Do you want to try starting the installation again?

> [Restart the installer]

> [close report]

This might be important:

So far I've tried using another PC but that didn't help

I don't have internet access with the PC that I want the Server to be on.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you trying to use the whole drive of the computer, or only part of the drive (alongside another operating system)? The 'curtin' installer of Ubuntu Server is tricky, but if you intend to use the whole drive, create a fresh partition table with gparted booted from another live drive, for example Ubuntu Desktop. After that the installer of Ubuntu Server should work. - Otherwise, let us know what you want, and you can get alternative methods ...

Comment: @sudodus That worked! Thanks for the fast and easy answer.

Comment: I'm glad I could help you solve the problem. Congratulations that you have a working Ubuntu Server :-)

Comment: With some luck, this issue [maybe easier in the future](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-server-is-still-too-difficult-to-install/25679/2) with @sudodus raising it at the community hub.  Thanks to both of you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK so I figured it out.

I booted the PC with an Ubuntu 20.04 OS, clicked "Try out Ubuntu" and remade the partition on the Harddrive I wanted the Server to boot on.

That solved it.